# SIGABRT error after last Xamarin.iOS update

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Just updated to the lastest version of Xamarin studio and Xamarin.iOS. Now I am getting this error:

Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.

Well, its not even an error actually. The simulator just crashes and and no workable error shows up. All was fine 10 mins ago...

Im on Mac OSX.

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT

2015-05-08 08:46:58.951 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] Unhandled managed exception:
Could not load file or assembly 'Splat.Portable' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
  at System.AppDomain.Load (System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.AppDomain.Load (System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef) [0x00000] in :0 
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.CollectReferencedAssemblies (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 assemblies, System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.CollectReferencedAssemblies (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 assemblies, System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x00000] in :0 
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.CollectReferencedAssemblies (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 assemblies, System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x00000] in :0 
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.RegisterEntryAssembly (System.Reflection.Assembly entry_assembly) [0x00000] in :0 
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.RegisterEntryAssembly (IntPtr a) [0x00000] in :0 
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.register_entry_assembly (IntPtr assembly) [0x00000] in :0 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Runtime:register_entry_assembly (intptr)
2015-05-08 08:46:58.953 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical: Stacktrace:

2015-05-08 08:46:58.953 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical: 
Native stacktrace:

2015-05-08 08:46:58.962 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  0   ReflectMobileiOS                    0x001baee7 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 311
2015-05-08 08:46:58.963 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  1   ReflectMobileiOS                    0x001c1c31 sigabrt_signal_handler + 129
2015-05-08 08:46:58.963 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x07fec03b _sigtramp + 43
2015-05-08 08:46:58.963 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
2015-05-08 08:46:58.963 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  4   libsystem_sim_c.dylib               0x07d83a5a abort + 156
2015-05-08 08:46:58.963 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  5   ReflectMobileiOS                    0x00350b46 xamarin_unhandled_exception_handler + 342
2015-05-08 08:46:58.964 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  6   ReflectMobileiOS                    0x001bb75b mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 91
2015-05-08 08:46:58.964 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  7   ReflectMobileiOS                    0x001ba5e8 mono_handle_exception_internal + 6200
2015-05-08 08:46:58.964 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  8   ReflectMobileiOS                    0x001b8da9 mono_handle_exception + 41
2015-05-08 08:46:58.964 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  9   ReflectMobileiOS                    0x0014fcd8 mono_x86_throw_exception + 136
2015-05-08 08:46:58.964 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  10  ???                                 0x130d8f57 0x0 + 319655767
2015-05-08 08:46:58.965 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  11  ???                                 0x131522d0 0x0 + 320152272
2015-05-08 08:46:58.965 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  12  ???                                 0x131521e8 0x0 + 320152040
2015-05-08 08:46:58.965 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  13  ???                                 0x1315216c 0x0 + 320151916
2015-05-08 08:46:58.965 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  14  ???                                 0x13152198 0x0 + 320151960
2015-05-08 08:46:58.965 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  15  ???                                 0x13152198 0x0 + 320151960
2015-05-08 08:46:58.966 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  16  ???                                 0x1315208c 0x0 + 320151692
2015-05-08 08:46:58.966 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  17  ???                                 0x13151fb8 0x0 + 320151480
2015-05-08 08:46:58.966 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  18  ???                                 0x13151f6c 0x0 + 320151404
2015-05-08 08:46:58.966 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  19  ???                                 0x13126b90 0x0 + 319974288
2015-05-08 08:46:58.966 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  20  ReflectMobileiOS                    0x0034f8e0 xamarin_register_entry_assembly + 32
2015-05-08 08:46:58.967 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  21  ReflectMobileiOS                    0x0034d471 xamarin_main + 1889
2015-05-08 08:46:58.967 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  22  ReflectMobileiOS                    0x00074ff1 main + 113
2015-05-08 08:46:58.967 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:  23  libdyld.dylib                       0x07cdfac9 start + 1

## 2015-05-08 08:46:58.967 ReflectMobileiOS[1761:93636] critical:

Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries

## used by your application.

Comment: Could you set the logging to diagnostic in Xamarin Studio and see if there is any more detail about the error? My experience with the latest update is that the checks for IOS UI's are very strict. (Constraint errors etc.)

Comment: Hi Chris. I updated my questions. Thanks for your time so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got is working again. Turns out a NuGet package was not being found. Readded it and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I got a very similar SIGABRT before I added the camera permission to my info.plist.  Drove me crazy until I figured it out.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Please allow the camera to be used for Scanning Barcodes</string>
```