# Xamarin Forms iOS application crashes at startup

Tags: xamarin, mobile, xamarin.ios, crash

I have been fighting a bug for a few days now. I have been looking everywhere on a solution to this. I am at my end on what I can do.

Basically, my iOS app is crashing on startup. I am getting a SIGABT fault code with an error: `FIXME: ftnptr_arg page trampolines`. I will attach a copy of the crash report below. I found some posts that are a little similar to my issue on this site:

[Got a SIGABRT while executing native code xamarin.ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966787/got-a-sigabrt-while-executing-native-code-xamarin-ios)

[SIGABRT error after last Xamarin.iOS update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111395/sigabrt-error-after-last-xamarin-ios-update)

[Xamarin IOS app crashes with exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319655/xamarin-ios-app-crashes-with-exception-exc-bad-access-sigabrt)

and on GitHub:
https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/9871

I have tried these solutions and they do not work for me. I would also like to add that I am using the Bluetooth on the device. I did add the correct permissions in the Info.plist file. The Bluetooth library that I am using is Plugin.BLE: https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le

Anyways, the crash is happening on a page that does not access the bluetooth device. It is happening on a  log in page (which is the first page that is displayed to the user). I do not think that the issue is related to the bluetooth. Like I said previously, I am pretty much at the end of what I can do. Not sure what is going on. Has anyone else out there ran into the issue?

Additional Note:

I would like to also add that I am able to debug the initialization of the form and step through the code without it crashing. I only have 3 functions. One for initialization, another for when the form appears, and a third for when a button is pressed. I can step through the code on the first 2 functions. After the program executes these two, the app crashes. I know that it is not an issue with my code because the same code runs fine on Android.

Also, I would create a minimalist code to post, however, the app includes a number of pictures and graphics that I think would be too large to post here. And I do not think that the issue is related to the code that I wrote. As said above, the code runs fine on Android.

Crash debug report:

```
[HotReload] (2020-04-08 15:31:50.1): WARN: (PQEApplicationv3.iOS) Hot Reload disabled due to invalid linker settings
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/System.Numerics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/System.Drawing.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/.monotouch-32/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/System.Net.Http.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/System.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.dll [External]
Thread started:  #2
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/Xamarin.Essentials.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/Plugin.BLE.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/PQEApplicationv3.dll
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.exe
2020-04-08 11:31:53.660 PQEApplicationv3.iOS[403:658622] error: FIXME: ftnptr_arg page trampolines

=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x3ff556b - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x3fed549 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_handle_native_crash
    0x3ff4c2f - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : sigabrt_signal_handler
    0x1d8c0259 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : _sigtramp
    0x1d8c6087 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : pthread_kill
    0x1d7a295b - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib : abort
    0x4357d4c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libxamarin-debug.dylib : _ZL12log_callbackPKcS0_S0_iPv
    0x4123ca1 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : eglib_log_adapter
    0x3fcbfb7 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : monoeg_g_logv_nofree
    0x3fcbff5 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : monoeg_g_log
    0x3fd98cb - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_aot_get_ftnptr_arg_trampoline
    0xdc74f - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/PQEApplicationv3.iOS : (null)
    0x3ff7957 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_jit_compile_method_with_opt
    0x3ffea7b - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_delegate_trampoline
    0x72d494 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmscorlib.dll.dylib : generic_trampoline_delegate
    0x6bc6a0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmscorlib.dll.dylib : wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
    0x3ffc1ad - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x408f937 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x40924cb - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_runtime_invoke
    0xbc649 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/PQEApplicationv3.iOS : (null)
    0xbd241 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/PQEApplicationv3.iOS : (null)
    0x1e985b2f - /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation : <redacted>
    0x1dffbfdd - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : <redacted>
    0x1dffbaa5 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : <redacted>
    0x1dff9f51 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : <redacted>
    0x1df4d1af - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    0x1df4cfd1 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFRunLoopRunInMode
    0x1f6f7b41 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices : GSEventRunModal
    0x232d5a53 - /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit : UIApplicationMain
    0xf57924 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib : wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr
    0xea7358 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib : UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr
    0xea72dc - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib : UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string
    0x16a9c8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libPQEApplicationv3.iOS.exe.dylib : PQEApplicationv3_iOS_Application_Main_string__
    0x6bc6a0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmscorlib.dll.dylib : wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
    0x3ffc1ad - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x408f937 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
The app has been terminated.
    0x409447d - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked
The app has been terminated.
    0x3fdeecb - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_jit_exec
    0x436dd24 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/libxamarin-debug.dylib : xamarin_main
    0xdbe95 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4F25BE08-0DD1-4153-BAB0-DD4EAD436163/PQEApplicationv3.iOS.app/PQEApplicationv3.iOS : (null)
    0x1d73a4eb - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x1d80dacc):
0x1d80dabc  1c ff 2f 
e1 1e ff 2f e1 52 cf 
a0 e3 80 
00 00 ef  .
./...
/.R.......
0x1d80dacc  04 00 00 3a 04 c0 9f e5 0c c0 9f e7 00 00 00 ea  ...:.......
....
.
0x1d80dadc  4c 
05 70 1a 1c ff 2f e1 1e ff 
2f e1 53 cf a0 
e3  L.p.../.../
.S...
0x1d80daec  80 00 00 ef 04 00 00 3a 04 
c0 9f 
e5 0c c0 9f e7  
......
.:......
..

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher:Apply <0x0002f>
      at System.Object:runtime_invoke_dynamic <0x000fb>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain <0x0004f>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x00033>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x00057>
      at PQEApplicationv3.iOS.Application:Main <0x00097>
      at System.Object:runtime_invoke_dynamic <0x000fb>
=================================================================
```

Edit:

I should note that this app is for a personal project and not related to any app on the app store

Comment: if the crash is happening on a specific page, then it's not accurate to say "at startup".  Do you have any exception handling in that page?  What about a crash reporting tool like appcenter.ms?  Are you using the latest versions of all the tools and libraries?

Comment: Hello Jason, thank you for your feedback. Yes, I am using the latest version of Xamarin sdk and visual studio. Due to the simplicity of the page, I do not have any exception handling. I stepped through the code on the page and nothing there errors out. It occurs a little after the page is loaded.

Comment: I strongly suggest you use a crash reporting tool.  Does it always cause the same crash on different devices and emulators?

Comment: Alright, I will download a crash reporting tool and analyze it this way. Will post an update later. The code is meant for iOS 10 or up. I have an iPhone 5 that I am testing on. As for the simulator, all I get is a black screen

Comment: no, I mean a tool like appcenter.ms.  If you can't get it to work at all on the emulator, that would be a sign something is wrong.  Do you have any code in the appdelegate or app.xaml.cs that could be an issue?

Comment: Can you check if the interpreter is enabled ? You seem to be using a 32bits device and the interpreter is (right now) only working on 64bits devices,

Comment: @poupou Thank you for your feedback. I do have the Mono interpreter selected in the build settings. If there is another interpreter setting, can you tell me where it is located?

Comment: @Jason After a long delay, I got appcenter.ms set up. I am not sure if I am doing it right as nothing appears in the diagnostic menu. But I do have this in the Analytics->Log Flow: `HANDLEDERROR - {"error_id":"caa027c8-41f8-47d1-842e-0558a6b7585b"}` not sure if this means anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so for now the answer that I used to solve this was that I changed iPhones. I was running on a iPhone 5C. Now doing an iPhone SE (Not the 2020 model).

For now, this will be the answer. However, I will leave the question open as I would like to know why the code did not execute on the iPhone 5C.